# Should I return id of associated entity or whole entity

Tags: rest, api-design

OK, lets assume we have two entities: **Profile**, consisting of `id`, name and ~10 irrelevant fields, and **Post**, consisting of `text`, `title`, and it's `author` (Profile). Also, there is resource */feed* that returns feed containing posts from different profiles.

So I have two options:

1. Send full **Profile** entity in author
2. Send author's id (there is a way to request **Profiles** separately)

Which way is faster (in terms on using it on front end) and more convenient (RESTy, if you like).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously just sending the `id` of `Profile` is faster because the response length is smaller.

The important question, however, do you need the full `Profile` object with each `Post`? If you want to, for example, print out the name of the author for each `Post` then sending the full object makes more sense. But if you want to just supply a link to the author with each `Post` (in the front end) then the `id` should be enough.

For other services that query yours for `Post`s just send the `id` and have them make a second call if they need. They can always cache the data on their end if needed.

Try to build your service so that each call/endpoint returns the **bare minimum** amount of data needed to make sense of the response. This might mean that a `Post` contains a lean `Profile` object where only the name is included but all the other, "irrelevant", fields are excluded. But when you query a `Profile` directly, you get the full object.

You can also have an optional query parameter where the caller can specify whether they want just the `id` or the full `Profile`, this is a strategy [Atlassian JIRA](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/#expansion) uses to preserve bandwidth and improve speed.

Also check out the [`hal+json`](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) specification, it can give you good ideas about how to design a more usable and transparent REST service.

**MOST IMPORTANT**! Your endpoints should only return data that the outside world can actually use and make sense of. So that means if `Profile` has a field/fields which values are only used in your back-end (like, for example, the user's password) then you should never leak those out.