# Rest API is it ok to return individual user data inside a resource?

Tags: rest, api-design

For the sake of example, say I have an API which handles passing details of books back to a mobile application. Users can browser a list of books, and add books to their wish list.

My question is, when returning a single book, or a collection of books, is it good practice to include user specific information with each book resource? By this I mean, with each book is it ok to include a field which denotes whether or not that book is in the users wish list, or would this list be returned separately and be up to the mobile application to perform this check.

The mobile app developers would prefer to make a call to /books and receive a response looking something like this;

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "How to be good at everything",
      "price": 3.99,
      "in_wish_list": true
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "How to be good at nothing",
      "price": 6.50,
      "in_wish_list": false
    }
    ]
}
```

Where I think I would prefer to have this data split across multiple endpoints;

/user/29/wishlist

```
{
  "wishlist": [1,7,9,34,28]
}
```

/books

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "How to be good at everything",
      "price": 3.99
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name": "How to be good at nothing",
      "price": 6.50
    }
    ]
}
```

This way the mobile application is responsible for determining if a book is in a users wish list.

I can see the benefits of embedding the user data into the book resource, but it doesn't feel right.

I wonder how other manage this kind of situation?

Comment: Practically everybody who designs an API deals with this kind of situation. Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685396/should-i-return-id-of-associated-entity-or-whole-entity/39685477#39685477) to a very similar question, it should also apply here.

Comment: Thanks, client developers are always going to want as much information as possible in a single request/response, especially when a particular view within a mobile application requires that information. Although I agree this does aid with the integration with a mobile application, it feels to me like the API is being specifically tailored to a client. I guess what I'm doing is weighing up between returning responses that are tailored to a mobile applications view, against returning responses across multiple endpoints and forcing the client application to do more work by making more calls.

Answer (score 0):

Now it all depends on who will consume your API, and how. If there's a requirement for displaying the user's wishlisted books, then a separate endpoint is a must. Of course mobile client developers will prefer one hefty call to several smaller ones, but you can also compromise and have both a separate user wishlist endpoint (again, if there's a use case scenario for that), and return a boolean per book - that way, the number of calls towards you API might even reduce.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely semantical point of view, nothing could stop you from creating a separate resource ‘book data for a specific user’

```
GET /user-books?user_id=<user_id>
{
  "books": [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name": "How to be good at everything",
      "price": 3.99,
      "in_wish_list": true
    }
    …
  ]
}
```

It doesn't violate any REST constraint. Note that operation is stateless (takes `user_id` from query string) and cacheable.